# UniWebView 5.7.3 prefab not displaying website

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, uniwebview

I just bought [UniWebView](https://uniwebview.com/) and the demo doesn't work.

I tried it with the included Demo and also in a separate scene I made.
When I build to android it doesn't throw any errors nor any warnings, it builds perfectly.
On the phone when I try it it just shows blue, doesn't open the website, nothing.

There isn't really any code since I just used the demo and the prefab.

[This is the build output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZnnR.png)

Comment: Here you go: [UniWebView - Technical Support Request](https://onevcat.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/2/group/2/create/10010) -> In general first ask the authors of libraries. Way more effective and efficient than letting us here guess around based on vague knowledge (or in this case lack of any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might've had the same problem as me:
It turns out i had custom android manifest enabled. Turning it off fixed it for me.